# Call a contact in android

Tags: android, call, contacts

I have wrote an android app that uses voice recognition and save voice into a string.Now i can access to different part of this string and for example when i say call dad i need to retrieve dad's number from contacts.

```
   private void call() {
  Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("0000000000"));
  try{
     startActivity(in);
  }

  catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

}

I know this function but instead of giving Uri.parse the actual number, i need to pass dad's number to it.For example something like Uri.parse(dad.PhoneNumber).How can i retrieve a phone number from contacts by using a name ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to obtain the number from a contact you know only the name, so:

```
    // Define the fields that the query will return
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    // Execute the query and receive the cursor with the results
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?", 
                    new String[] { "Name of the Contact" },
                    null );
```

Change the "Name of the contact" with your contact name...

Now you can get the value from cursor

```
// First discover the index of the desired field (Number)
final int indexNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
String number = cursor.getString(indexNumber);
```

Then you can use your intent.

PS: The example uses a LIKE operator, because of this you can find more than one result in the cursor. Adapt to you necessity.

Comment: Thanks, but i get this error:     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shahin.test/com.example.shahin.test.call}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: Try checking if the cursor returned a valid value. Just after creating the cursor add:

    if (cursor != null) {  
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
            // First discover the index of the desired field (Number)  
            final int indexNumber =             cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);  
            String number = cursor.getString(indexNumber);  
        }  
    }  

If the value doesnt exists, then the cursor will be empty and this error may occur.